# When is Ubuntu TV available?

Tags: software-recommendation, ubuntu-tv

I am really interested in using Ubuntu TV, however the most recent posts that i could find are from 2012 and only explain how to install the "demo" version.

Does anyone know if this available, or when it will be? Also will this be available as a standalone package (ie, not built into TV)?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

At this time Ubuntu TV is only supported on Ubuntu 12.04. If you do not have 12.04 and would still like to help out we suggest that you use a virtual machine for now.

See [Install Ubuntu TV](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuTV/Contributing#Install_Ubuntu_TV) for more info, and how to install.

<sup>Source:UbuntuW</sup>